# Can I draw shapes like circle,rectangle,line etc outside drawRect method

Tags: ios, ipad, drawrect, cgcontextref

Can I draw shapes like circle, rectangle, line etc outside `drawRect` method using

```
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

or is it mandatory to use it inside `drawRect` only.
Please help me, let me know how can I draw shapes outside `drawRect` method.
Actually i want to go on plotting dots on `touchesMoved` event.

This is my code for drawing a dot.

```
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, CGRectMake(theMovedPoint.x, theMovedPoint.y, 8, 8));
```

Comment: Sure, create bit map contexts, draw into them, then create images from those.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basically you need a context to draw something. You can assume context as a white paper. `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` will return `null` if you are not in a valid context.In `drawRect` you get the context of the view.

Having said that, you can draw outside `drawRect` Method. You can begin an imageContext to draw things and add it to your view.

Look at the below example taken from [here](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/drawing-on-uiimages/),

```
    - (UIImage *)imageByDrawingCircleOnImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    // begin a graphics context of sufficient size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

    // draw original image into the context
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    // get the context for CoreGraphics
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // set stroking color and draw circle
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];

    // make circle rect 5 px from border
    CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake(0, 0,
                image.size.width,
                image.size.height);
    circleRect = CGRectInset(circleRect, 5, 5);

    // draw circle
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(ctx, circleRect);

    // make image out of bitmap context
    UIImage *retImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // free the context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return retImage;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For **Swift 4**

```
func imageByDrawingCircle(on image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height), false, 0.0)

    // draw original image into the context
    image.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)

    // get the context for CoreGraphics
    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    // set stroking color and draw circle
    ctx.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)

    // make circle rect 5 px from border
    var circleRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
    circleRect = circleRect.insetBy(dx: 5, dy: 5)

    // draw circle
    ctx.strokeEllipse(in: circleRect)

    // make image out of bitmap context
    let retImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

    // free the context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return retImage;
}
```