# BezierPath in Swift Using Playgrounds

Tags: ios, swift

Do I have to create a custom class in order to use the BezierPath in the Swift playgrounds?

The following code displays nothing but black background:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

class GraphView : UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
        path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0,0))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(50,100))
        path.closePath()
        UIColor.redColor().setFill()

        path.stroke()
    }

}


let graphView = GraphView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,960,640))
```

Comment: Set the view backgroundColor to white and you'll see your line. It's black, though, not red. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34659468/2227743 for fabulous tips.

Comment: I am using Playgrounds!

Comment: Yes, I know you are using Playgrounds. Look at my answer.

Comment: FYI, you set the fill color, but then only `stroke`. If you wanted to stoke, call `UIColor.redColor().setStroke()`. If you want to fill with `UIColor.redColor().setFill()`, call `fill`, not `stroke`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use this at the end of your code:

```
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = graphView
```

and to open the Playground's "Assistant Editor" to see the result.

*And also to change the background color of the view since it's black... and your line is also black. ;)*

Comment: I got it working but the left hand side Assistant Editor simply says "GraphView" it does not show the graph or the rendered output

Comment: [Screenshot of my Playground](https://www.evernote.com/l/AFnk7PAzYtBNIKHvk2LITLvkUQg4x261xz4) with the assistant panel on the right.

Comment: Swift 3+: `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = graphView`

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 5:

```
import UIKit

class GraphView : UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .white
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100))
        path.stroke()
    }

}

let graphView = GraphView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 960, height: 640))
```

[image: screenshot of view in playground]
Swift 5.2, Xcode 11.4