# How to start function drawRect(rect: CGRect) ? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cgrect

I have `rect:CGRect` function inside my app, how can i use it ? I try

```
  drawRect(CGRect,x1:33.33,y1:23.45)
```

but doesn't work my function under below.

```
func drawRect(rect: CGRect,x1: CGFloat, y1: CGFloat) {

let center = CGPoint(x:x1/2, y: y1/2)
let radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height)
let arcWidth: CGFloat = 100
let startAngle: CGFloat = 3 * π / 5.99
let endAngle: CGFloat = π / 1.40

let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                        radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2,
                        startAngle: startAngle,
                        endAngle: endAngle,
                        clockwise: true)


path.lineWidth = arcWidth
counterColor.setStroke()
path.stroke()


}
```

Comment: better to call `setNeedsDisplay` which can call `drawRect` itself for your view. Ultimately `drawRect` is called by itself whenever a view of its type is initialized

Comment: What doesn't work? That's **not** the `drawRect` method called by `setNeedsDisplay` or similar.

Comment: What is this custom `drawRect` method you have? It's not the right one from `UIView`.

Comment: ohh yes.. That is something different and not the one from `UIView`

Comment: You better rename your methode to get better answers and not frighten the friendly iOS reader. I supect you want to draw somthing which you can see on screen. In this case this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21312119/1457385

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call `drawRect` yourself. It's called by the framework when needed.

The proper solution is to call `setNeedsDisplay()` on the view. Call this whenever the state of the view changes such that you want `drawRect` to be called.

On top of this, you have the wrong `drawRect` method. The one from `UIView` only has one parameter - the `CGRect`.

And in Swift 3 it would be:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
}
```

Comment: dude yeah worked fine but how can i add parameters in function x1, y1 like ?

Comment: and i want to use it without override  ? which changes i need to do ?

Comment: You can't change the signature of the method. You need to use properties. Then anytime the values of these properties changes, call `setNeedsDisplay()`. And be sure your `draw` method uses the properties.

Comment: can you show setNeedsDisplay() sample codes changes inside my codes here ?  inside your answer TY

Comment: That's it, just call `setNeedsDisplay()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not call drawRect(). When you want to view to redraw, call the setNeedsDisplay() method.

Comment: The OP has a bigger problem - they have not implemented the proper `drawRect` method.

Comment: `setNeedsDisplay` will not call **that** particular method.

Comment: oops my bad. Did not realize its a custom drawRect method. Not sure if its a good idea to call a custom method drawRect too.