# Divide Square UIView into Cross Sections iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, divide

I have a square UIView which i need to divide into cross section with two different colors as shown [image: here]

Comment: Add a layer over the View and give them different color. To shape your layer use bezier path.

Comment: can you pls elaborate..!!?

Comment: Take ref from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311880/drawing-uibezierpath-on-code-generated-uiview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my code to achieve that graph:

```
//Define the drawing path
UIBezierPath *path1 = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
//path Move to start drawing position
[path1 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 100)];
//Draw a straight line from the starting position to（100, 200）
[path1 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
//To draw a line from (100, 200) to (200, 200)
[path1 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 200)];
//close path
[path1 closePath];

CAShapeLayer *layer1 = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
layer1.path = path1.CGPath;
layer1.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.88 green:0.87 blue:0.87 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:layer1];

UIBezierPath *path2 = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[path2 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 100)];
[path2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 200)];
[path2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 200)];
[path2 closePath];

CAShapeLayer *layer2 = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
layer2.path = path2.CGPath;
layer2.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.89 green:0.57 blue:0.53 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:layer2];
```

Here is the result:
[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5urLl.png)