# How to add round corner on irregular figure?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I want to round every corner of this.
I use UIBezierPath to draw and set

```
path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
path.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinRound;
```

that doesn't work.

Do I have a convenient way to do it,instead of a sequence of `addLineToPoint` and `addArcWithCenter`

[image]

In custom view

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(150, 100)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(150, 150)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 150)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 200)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(250, 200)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(250, 250)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 250)];
    [path closePath];
    path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    path.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinRound;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.greenColor.CGColor);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path.CGPath);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

In Viewcontroller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    testvvv *test = [[testvvv alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:test];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want this:

[image: rounded staircase]

There are Core Graphics functions for rounding corners that are not available on `UIBezierPath`. They are `CGContextAddArcToPoint` and `CGPathAddArcToPoint`. I'll explain how they work.

First let's consider how you draw two lines meeting at a sharp corner. When the path is first initialized, its “current point” is at the origin:

[image: current point at origin]

You use `CGPathMoveToPoint` to move to the start of the first line at `(x0, y0)`:

[image: after move]

Then you use `CGPathAddLineToPoint` to draw the first line, ending at the corner at `(x1, y1)`:

[image: after first line]

Finally, you use `CGPathAddLineToPoint` again to draw the second line to `(x2, y2)`:

[image: after second line]

Now let's use `CGPathAddArcToPoint` to round the corner instead. Rewind to just after you used `CGPathMoveToPoint` to move to the start of the first line:

[image: after move]

`CGPathAddArcToPoint` takes **two** points: the point at the corner (which won't be reached since it will round the corner) and the next point in the shape after the corner. So you pass it both `(x1,y1)` (the corner) and `(x2,y2)` (the end of the next line). You also pass it the radius of the corner:

[image: after first line and corner]

Notice that `CGPathAddArcToPoint` draws the first line for you, and draws arc that forms the rounded corner, and leaves the current point at the end of that arc. So you then use `CGPathAddLineToPoint` to draw the second line:

[image: after second line]

Okay, that explains (I hope) how `CGPathAddArcToPoint` works. `CGContextAddArcToPoint` works the same way, but operates on the context's path.

To apply this to your staircase shape, you want to use an `CG*AddArcToPoint` function to draw every corner. Since you have a closed shape and you want no sharp corners, you don't need to use `CG*AddLineToPoint` at all. You can use the arc function to draw every line as well as the rounded corners.

One thing to be careful of is where you start the shape. You can't start at a corner, because then you'd get a straight line out of the corner. Instead, it's easiest to start at the midpoint of one of the lines, far from any corner.

Also, since you're doing this in `drawRect:`, you can just use the context's path instead of creating a separate `UIBezierPath` or `CGPath` object. Here's the code I used to draw the result above:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGPoint p[] = {
        {100, 100},
        {150, 100},
        {150, 150},
        {200, 150},
        {200, 200},
        {250, 200},
        {250, 250},
        {100, 250},
    };
    size_t count = (sizeof p) / (sizeof p[0]);
    CGPoint pLast = p[count - 1];

    CGContextRef gc = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Start at the midpoint of one of the lines.
    CGContextMoveToPoint(gc, 0.5 * (pLast.x + p[0].x), 0.5 * (pLast.y + p[0].y));

    for (size_t i = 1; i < count; ++i) {
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(gc, p[i-1].x, p[i-1].y, p[i].x, p[i].y, 10);
    }
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(gc, pLast.x, pLast.y, p[0].x, p[0].y, 10);

    // Connect the last corner's arc to the starting point.
    CGContextClosePath(gc);

    [UIColor.greenColor setFill];
    CGContextFillPath(gc);
}
```

Comment: `{22, 104.33333333333333},
        {22, 135.33333333333334},
        {23.333333333333332, 136.33333333333334},
        {23.333333333333332, 167.33333333333334},
        {351, 167.33333333333334},
        {351, 136.33333333333334},
        {352, 135.33333333333334},
        {352, 104.33333333333333}` if i change to this array of rects, the shape goes wrong

Comment: Please post a new separate question with a picture of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add rounded corner in beizer path by using below method.

```
path.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: 300-10, y: 50), radius: 10 , startAngle: 0 , endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI/2)  , clockwise: true)
```

Comment: Yes,it can do it,but it may be too much line and arc to calculate,is there a convenient way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have added `kCGLineCapRound` is working fine.

`kCGLineCapRound` is for the path, try adding some `lineWidth` for the path.
You will see the difference.

```
path.lineWidth = 50.0
```

You can set its `strokeColor` same as your fill color if needed

[image]

A very good post on uibezierpath
[Drawing UIBezierPath on code generated UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311880/drawing-uibezierpath-on-code-generated-uiview/34659468#34659468)

Comment: @HensonFang please refer this post. Its a very good post on uibezierpath
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311880/drawing-uibezierpath-on-code-generated-uiview/34659468#34659468