# Redraw / setNeedsLayout of UIScrollView subview does not work

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I have create a simple, custom `UIView` subclass, `LineView`,  which overrides `drawRect:` to draw a line from the top right corner to the bottom left corner.

This `LineView` is placed as subview within a `UIScrollView` using fixed constraints for its height and width and top + leading constraints for its position.

When the `UIScrollView` is scrolled the width constraints is updated to to change the size of the line view:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    ...
    self.lineViewWidthConstraint.constant = someFactorRelatedToTheCurrentScrollPosition;
    [self.lineView setNeedsLayout];
}
```

**Problem:** Changing the width does **NOT** call the drawRect: method of the `LineView`. Thus the line is not redrawn but simply squeezed or stretched. Even using `setNeedsLayout` manually does not trigger the re-draw.

Any idea why the draw method is not called and how to fix this?

Comment: Move your code from 'drawRect' to 'layoutSubviews' methods

Comment: Thanks @iDhaval but how could I perform drawing in layoutSubviews?

Comment: Ultimately, drawing is done on layer. So you can draw your line using CAShapeLayer and UIBezierPath. Follow this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311880/drawing-uibezierpath-on-code-generated-uiview

Comment: Instead of `setNeedsLayout`, give `setNeedsDisplay` a try.

Comment: Thanks, adding a CALayer and updating it manually works fine and solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `layoutIfNeeded` instead of `setNeedsLayout`. As former is synchronous(forced) call and latter is async call.

Comment: Thanks, but the result is still the same.

Comment: @AndreiHerford Try using layoutIfNeeded on scrollview instance or your superview instance.