# Custom shape UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

Does anyone know how to create UIView with such shape?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIBezierPath to draw a mask layer to your UIView. After drawing you mask layer you can use `drawRect` or add a mask to your view's `layer.mask`. A similar question was asked before: [Drawing UIBezierPath on code generated UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311880/drawing-uibezierpath-on-code-generated-uiview)